# Protobuf and GRPC with maven not compiling

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, grpc

So I'm working with maven for the first time to learn grpc and protobuf, but after I gen the code, the generated java files do not compile. I tried generating the code in a seperate java project(and I dragged in all the jars by themselves, which were downloaded from maven repository), but that project somehow managed to compile. Does anyone know why this occurs?

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>maven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.14.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Some of the errors I get:

"the hierarchy of Feature is inconsistent"- in Feature.java

"The type com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" - in Feature.java, even though the protobuf lib is in the project

"The method bindService() of type RouteGuideGrpc.RouteGuideImplBase must override a superclass method" - in RouteGuideGrpc.java, even though it is overriding the method according to the api

Thanks!

Comment: I took your pom.xml, added a trailing </project>, and saved it. I then created src/main/proto/ and copied https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/raw/v1.14.0/examples/src/main/proto/route_guide.proto into it. I then ran `mvn compile` and it worked. Looking in target/classes/ I see compiled classes. I used Maven 3.5.2 with Java 1.8.0_121.